# Parse JSON with an array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have the following JSON string returned by a remote server:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "user_id": 1,
      "name": "Chris Rivers",
    },
    {
      "user_id": 3,
      "name": "Peter Curley",
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to iterate the users.

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)["users"].each do |user|
    puts user["name"]
end
```

As far as I understand, the problem is: ruby doesn't recognize `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)["users"]` as an array, and thus `puts` returns me only the first user.

How do I solve that problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have pasted is not valid JSON. The trailing comma after on each `"name"` is a problem

```
"name": "Chris Rivers",
```

You'll get a `LoadError` trying to decode this with `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode`

> MultiJson::LoadError: 399: unexpected token at '{"user_id": 1,"name": "Chris Rivers",},{"user_id": 3,"name": "Peter Curley",}]}'

If we clean up the JSON, turning it into something `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode` can understand

```
"{\"users\": [{\"user_id\": 1,\"name\": \"Chris Rivers\"},{\"user_id\": 3,\"name\": \"Peter Curley\"}]}"
```

you'll see there is no issue iterating over each object in `"users"` (`x` below is the above JSON string)

```
[8] pry(main)> ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(x)["users"].map { |user| user["name"] }
=> ["Chris Rivers", "Peter Curley"]
```

Answer (score 8):

Does your source data actually have the trailing commas after each user's name? I get a parse error for that, but your code works as you want it to if I remove them:

```
json = '{ "users": [ { "user_id": 1, "name": "Chris Rivers" }, { "user_id": 3, "name": "Peter Curley" } ]}'
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json)["users"].each do |user|
   puts user["name"]
end
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't not recognizing the array, it's the trailing commas after the `"name"` elements.

Removing those allows JSON parsing to proceed normally:

```
pry(main)> ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(s)["users"]
=> [{"user_id" => 1, "name" => "Chris Rivers"},
    {"user_id" => 3, "name" => "Peter Curley"}]
```